# Where to find the valid structure of filebeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm trying to config a simple filebeat.yml file, but I get syntax errors and I cannot find more details on what is the correct structure for that. Here is my filebeat.yml file but I get the error "line 8: did not find expected '-' indicator"

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - input_type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/telnet.log
#      fields:  {nodeIP: "130.245.82.32"}
      document_type: telnet

     - input_type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/ssh.log
      document_type: myssh

  registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry
.......
```

How can I find what it expects to see?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in my YML code, there is one space before the second input_type that messed up everything.